# Join activities with users makes redundant rows, I just want first activity

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am on a postgres database

So I have a raw sql query like the following I intend to use to query the database

```
Select
acts.created_at as "firstActivity",
users.*
from  users
join activities acts on acts.user_id = users.id 
and acts.created_at > users.created_at 
and acts.created_at < users.updated_at
where users.region_id='1'
```

the problem is that there are multiple activities in between the user's creation and update. The created_at and updated_at fields are of course dates like the following `2021-11-10 09:27:14+00`

I would like to only return the first activity of those activities between the two times.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `DISTINCT ON (expression)`, this is probably what you need

```
Select DISTINCT ON (users.id) id, acts.created_at as "firstActivity",
from users
join activities acts on acts.user_id = users.id 
and acts.created_at > users.created_at 
and acts.created_at < users.updated_at
where users.region_id='1'
Order by users.id, acts.created_at
```

[See documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Answer (score 0):

well if I underattended your question right

you should use the function
`min(created_at/updated_at)`

in your query and you can add the condition of between the dates A and B

Comment: It should definitely be  a min on the activities.created_at so let us say we have 4 activities in between user created and user updated I want to get the first of those activities. Unfortunately I am not very good with SQL (having generally worked with people who are much better at it and they handle it) - so I don't know how to structure the min in a way that works here.

Comment: well a question pops here , do you store the logs of the changes in a database ? bec I your main let us day USERS table only have one date store and as updated just the date will change. you have to query in you logs table

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to join the first activity per user, then use a lateral join:

```
select
  a.created_at as "firstActivity",
  u.*
from  users u
cross join lateral
(
  select *
  from activities acts 
  where acts.user_id = u.id 
  and acts.created_at > u.created_at 
  and acts.created_at < u.updated_at
  order by acts.created_at
  fetch first row only
) a
where u.region_id = '1';
```

By joining only the rows you are interested in, you prevent from getting a big intermediate result that you must then deal with afterwards.